# Fetch me all the active creatives of a line item

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-toolbar

I am new to dfp tags. What I am trying to achieve is fetch all the active creatives for associated line item for a particular ad unit.

### What I have done till now :

a) Chrome extension Google Publisher Toolbar:  gets me the current creative. 
Doesn't help me in getting the queued creatives for that ad unit and associated line item
b) doubleclick-gpt-googletag  : same as above. Not getting the queued up creatives.

Thing is I get all the currently serving ads in the page.

In order to fetch all active creatives for a AD unit and line item, my last resort will be to use DFP based APIs, like creating my custom  query/API.

Appreciate any inputs, request any help for achieving the result above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad selection process in DFP is to choose the winning line item first and then choose the best creative that associates with that line item. [Review ad selection process here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1143651?hl=en)

It's the line item setting that plays a bigger role, not the creative.

Google Publisher Toolbar or DFP Console shows you only the line item selection process but doesn't show a level lower (creative selection process).

For example, there're 3 line items competing. After DFP chooses the winning line item, prioritizing or queuing the creatives of the lost line items is unnecessary.

You can click on "Delivery Diagnostics" for that ad unit on DFP Console and click on the winning line item to see all of the creative associates with it.